# Cantor space and Prefix metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $2^N$ be the set $2^N=$ $\{$ $w_0w_1....$ $:$ $w_i \in$ $\{$ $0,1$ $\}$ $\}$. There exists a metric d on $2^N$ defined as 
For $x=a_0a_1....$ and $y=b_0b_1.....$
$d(x,y)=0 \iff x=y$ and $d(x,y)=2^{-n}$ where $n=min$ $\{$ $P$ $:$ $a_P\neq b_P$ $\}$

I would like to show that for $x,y\in 2^w$, there exists an isometry $g:2^N\rightarrow 2^N$ such that $g(x)=y$.
I would like hints on this please.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $2^N$ as an algebra of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ then a satisfactory $g$ can easily be defined by the formula $g(z)=z+y-x$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $p,q\in 2^\omega$ and we want $g(p)=q$

So define define $g$ coordinatewise by the condition that for all $n$ $g(x)_n = x_n$ if $p_n = q_n$ and $g(x)_n = 1-x_n$ if $p_n \neq q_n$. As $g$ is a product map of swaps and identity maps, it's imediate that $g$ is an isometry, and by construction $g(p)=q$.

Comment: What's a good way to start thinking about those specific problems?

Comment: @topologicalmagician hard to say. This particular one is quite obvious.

Comment: What would be a similar problem? I've been trying to find one.